# Getting 500 error from API request for my node.js express app

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a custom module that sends a API request and receives JSON.

**data.js**

```
var data = function(callback) {

    var request = require('request')
    request.post('https://getpocket.com/v3/get', {
      headers: {'content-type':'application/json'},
      body: JSON.stringify({
        consumer_key:'...',
        access_token:'...',
        tag: 'nodejs'
      })
    }, function (err, res, body) {
      callback(body);
    })
}

module.exports = data;
```

And the route that will render the data.

**index.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

var data = require('../lib/data.js');

router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {

    data( function(data) {
        console.log(data)
        res.render('index', { 
            title: 'Express', 
            body: data
        });
    });
});

module.exports = router;
```

With this structure I always get `GET / 500 1129.898 ms - 1725`

If I place the API request implementation in **app.js** like the following, I'm getting the data without 500 error.

**app.js**

```
var request = require('request')
    request.post('https://getpocket.com/v3/get', {
      headers: {'content-type':'application/json'},
      body: JSON.stringify({
        consumer_key:'...',
        access_token:'...',
        tag: 'nodejs'
      })
    }, function (err, res, body) {

      //callback body
    })
```

But having this in **app.js**, I'm not sure how to pass the data to the route **index.js** and make the callback work and also not sure if app.js is the right place for this implementation so I'm hoping to make my custom module **data.js** work but what can possibly cause 500 error?

Comment: do you have the same `data` from `console.log(data)` when you get 500 error, and with working code?

Comment: Yes I get the same data for both structures. And only the former structure with data.js throws 500 error.

Comment: Console log the "res" object in the callback function, it may be null.

Comment: I don't even get anything when I try to log `res`, same thing with `data` the connection doesn't seem to work.  It would work in app.js though

Comment: try to replace `res.render` with `res.send(data)` and debug it like REST API. if it works in both cases -> you have problems inside your view renderer, like a template engine.